# Using Not in , Like and within a select SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Table 1:

```
OwnerID    CompanyFormula
a               a+b
b               b+c
c               c+d
```

Table 2:

```
CompanyID
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

I'm trying to write an SQL statement to retrieve any `CompanyID` that is not in Table 1's `OwnerID` or Table 1's `CompanyFormula`, meaning that it should only return `CompanyID` **`f`**.

My SQL:

```
Select Distinct CompanyID from 
(
   Select CompanyID
   from table2
   where CompanyID not in (Select OwnerID from table1)  

   union

   --Error and I need to select the CompanyID not companyFormula
   Select CompanyFormula not like '%'+(Select CompanyID from table1)  +'%'
)
```

Error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Do i need a join? How do I phrase the second line to get the `CompanyID` instead of `CompanyFormula`?

Comment: What does CompanyFormula mean? Is there any reason it's not two separate columns? Generally, normalized database design strongly discourages combining data into a single column. Your question is an example of why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this with `not exists` and `find_in_set()`:

```
select *
from table2 t2
where not exists (
   select 1
   from table1 t1
   where t1.OwnerId = t2.CompanyId
   or find_in_set(t2.CompanyId, replace(t1.CompanyFormula, '+', ','))
);
```

Note that in table 1 you appear to be storing a list of something in a string field.  This is generally a bad idea.  You should think about normalizing your data structure so table 1 would have multiple rows for each owner, with each row having one company.

EDIT:

In SQL Server (or any other database), you would use similar logic using `like`:

```
select *
from table2 t2
where not exists (
   select 1
   from table1 t1
   where t1.OwnerId = t2.CompanyId
   or '+' + t1.CompanyFormula + '+' like '%+' + t2.CompanyId + '+%'
);
```

The additional delimiters (`'+'`s) are to prevent partial matches (say "hen" from matching "then").

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify, im using Mircosoft SQL 2008 i dont think they have the function find_in_set.

Comment: @JoshuaTan . . . You just use `like` instead (no big deal).  You should tag your questions with the database you are using.  Oddly, I saw "My SQL" and just interpreted that as your database.

Comment: maybe i tagged wrongly, sorry. Thanks for your answer :D fantastic